# MSAccess event when new record is created

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use the current event to update the RecordSource property of a subform based on the ID of the record on the parent form. The problem arises in new records, because the ID field (which is an autonumber) is null. I test for the null ID to avoid errors, but I need to update the RecordSource as soon as the record is created, when the user types the first character.

The problem is that both Dirty and BeforeInsert events are triggered **before** the record is actually created, thus before the ID is assigned. I need an event that will trigger **after** the ID autonumber is assigned.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm not sure you can. You're correct to worry about checking the current max id;  the autonumber value could be higher than that if the top rows were just deleted.  http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/ms-access/49272-how-do-i-get-new-row-id-access-database-table-before-insert-new-row.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an After Insert event that will do what you want-- it fires after the record has been inserted and therefore the ID is in existence.

Comment: AfterInsert triggers after the record is saved. I need an event before then i.e. as soon as the user types a character and the AutoNumber is created.

Comment: To clarify: When a user is typing, the only events that you can work with will be On Key Down, On Key Up, on KeyPress. When they stop typing and the textbox loses focus, then all the events (onchange,beforeupdate,afterupdate etc.) fire.

Likewise, the AutoNumber isn't created until the record is saved, although if you're using vanilla access, this will happen as soon as the text box loses focus.

What I typically do with bound subforms is either Link Master Fields & Link Child Fields since access can handle null Id's fine by itself, Or

Comment: set visible = false after the user navigates to a new record, and set visible = true again afterInsert

Comment: tl;dr : you can't get what you want, but if you try sometimes, you can get something that works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, the event you want to use is the Onchange event.  In order for this to work on your form, the first control that gets focus must have this event available (i.e. Textbox ).  I don't know which control gets the focus first on your form but if it has this event then you can capture the first stroke of a key and run the procedure you wish at that time. At the first keystroke, the ID is created and the textbox or whatever control being used captures each keystroke until the control is exited. The only thing to be aware of is that this event is called each time a key is pressed so you will have to create some type of status variable to set showing that what you wanted done has been run and not to do it again.

```
    dim status as integer(must be declared at form declaration level.)
    if not status then
       do procedure
       Status =-1
    end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this, but how about using dirty and newrecord together?

i.e.:

`If Me.NewRecord And Me.Dirty Then
    'user has created a new record that has not yet been saved
End If`